# How to write a decorator that make property readonly in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I want to write a decorator that make a property of a class really readonly, which maybe set a writable false descriptor or one with get and set.

The property decorator function may have two or three arguments. When I write such code.

```js
class Circle {
  @readonly
  public magic: number = 3.14159;
}
```

The third parameter is always undefined, and I cannot just return a new descripter since I need the value to initialize the property.

I've tried to use a set and get to work around the initialization problem. Something like:

```js
function readonly(target: any, key: string, descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor) {
  if (descriptor) {
    descriptor.writable = false;
    return descriptor;
  }
  return {
    get: function get() {
      // Return the stored value for the instance.
    },
    set: function set() {
      // Check if it is the first time to set value.
      // If true store the value, else console.error.
    }
  };
}
```

And this seems to work, since the constructor will only set the value to property once.

However when I tried to extends a class like:

```js
class Circle {
  @readonly
  public magic: number = 3.14159;
}
class SemiCircle extends Circle {
  @readonly
  public magic: number = 3.14159 / 2.0;
}
```

The constructor of the SemiCircle will set the magic twice, first in super (the Circle constructor) and second by itself.

Is there any way to handle this problem. The `Listing 3 - Proposed JavaScript output:` which has an initializer in descriptor by https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4736 can work for me, but the issue seems to be suspended due to the outdated proposal.

Should I look up the setter and getter and get the count of set in consturctor, or write a typescript transformer (plugin) myself?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dpdrhg) would work?  You basically want to wait until the constructor is finished before making the prop immutable

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, this works for me (I've never thought of cooperating with class decorator). And for non-primitive type value, there should be a map to keep value for each instance instead of sharing one value.